# Masked Edit Extender text being deleted when typing an extra character according to maxlength

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm having a strange problem with the Masked Edit Extender. I need to add a Mask and a Max Length Property to some text input at runtime according to a selected value of a Drop Down List.  It works fine in almost all browsers, but in IE 8 and, according to another user, is also happening on IE 11, when I type an extra character that exceeds the Max Length, the current value of the text input gets erased and the New character typed Is captured erasing everything else.

I don't know what is the problem with these browser and if there is already a fix for that or I'm doing something wrong.

This is the big panorama:

When changing the option of the DropDownList I know the MaxLength and the Mask To Being Shown.

So my code is something like this (everything is inside of an update panel):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCardType" runat="server" Width="334px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCardType_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountNumber" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="328px" MaxLength="18"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAccountNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAccountNumber"
                                                                                        ErrorMessage="Type the account number">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeAccountNumber" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAccountNumber"
                                                                                        MessageValidatorTip="true" OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
                                                                                        InputDirection="LeftToRight" ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" Mask="9999999999999999"
                                                                                        ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" /> 


<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevAccountNumber" runat="server" ControlExtender="meeAccountNumber"
                                                                                        ControlToValidate="txtAccountNumber" IsValidEmpty="false" InvalidValueMessage="Invalid Account"
                                                                                        Display="Dynamic" EmptyValueMessage="Account cannot be empty" ErrorMessage="Invalid Account" />


protected void ddlCardType_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<crmBank> oListBanks = ViewState["oListBanks"] as List<crmBank>;
        var oSelectedBank = oListBanks.Where(i => i.Id == ddlBank.SelectedValue).SingleOrDefault();
        var oSelectedCard = oSelectedBank.CardList.Where(i => i.Id == ddlCardType.SelectedValue).SingleOrDefault();
        LimitText(oSelectedCard.Length);
        meeAccountNumber.Mask = oSelectedCard.Mask;
        meeAccountNumber.EnsureValid();
    }

    private void LimitText(int characters)
    {
        txtAccountNumber.MaxLength = caracteres;
        if (txtAccountNumber.Text.Trim().Length > txtAccountNumber.MaxLength)
        {
            txtAccountNumber.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

The current mask values that I'm having right now is

- 9999999999999999 (Max Length 16)
- 9999-9999-9999-9999 (Max Length 19)
- 9999-999999-9999 (Max Length 17)

I need to get the value for the Text Input with the mask so that's why I'm using `ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false"`

So in the first mask if my user types the character 17, for example 0123456789123456**7** all the value gets erased instead of the HTML max length property prevent the extra character typed so it stays in 0123456789123456, it becomes to just 7

Does anyone know what is happening or what can be happening and how I can make this works in all browsers?

I'm open to JQuery options or something like that. I just need to get the value according to a dynamic mask based on a dropDownList Value in case there is not a fix for this. But just remembering that the mask an max length will change dinamically so I need to do some ajax calls to get that values.

I know that I have to post what I have tried but, I think its an specific problem with the masked edit extender, because if I dont put a mask, the Max Length property resolved at runtime works as expected. It prevents for extra characters to be typed, so there must be something with that

Also The ajax toolkit version that I'm using was downloaded with nuget so I should have almost the most recent.

According to NUget I have the 7.0725. If I click on references a properties it says that the Version is : 3.5.7.725 And runtime version v2.0.50727

Thanks for your valuable help,